# java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I am getting this issue with **Retrofit**  but with postman it is working fine.

> java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on
>   Connection{2.test.esb.demoapp.com:80, proxy=DIRECT
>   hostAddress=2.test.esb.demoapp.com/172.16.33.156:80 cipherSuite=none
>   protocol=http/1.1}

Calling retrofit api with following method:

```
override fun registerDevice(deviceType: String, deviceId: String, deviceToken: String, description: String): Flowable<DefaultResponse> {

    val paramObject = JSONObject()
    paramObject.put("deviceType","2")
    paramObject.put("deviceId","45334343434dsdsdfgvxfg")
    paramObject.put("deviceToken","fgfdsd3443434sdsdsd")
    paramObject.put("description","Test")


    var deviceRegisterSuccess = demoService.registerNewDevice(paramObject)
    return deviceRegisterSuccess;

}
```

**DemoService.kt**

```
interface DemoService {

@POST("/v1/device/register")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
fun registerNewDevice(@Body request: JSONObject) : Flowable<DefaultResponse>

}
```

Comment: Have you got any solutions?

Comment: @Naveen  - The app API only works in network which is in VPN , so I switched my wifi to VPN(wifi) and problem solved